# Convert Spring MVC <form:select> to HTML <select> with JSTL <c:forEach>

Tags: html, spring-mvc, foreach, jstl

I am sending an ArrayList to this jsp file and reading it with this code:

```
<form:select path="student.ec[0].estate">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select one ---" />
    <form:options items="${estate}" />
</form:select>
```

Because I have **path** attribute in the above html, it stores the selected value in an appropriate bean. And I can also easily print it. But I want the above code to be converted to JSTL code. I want to be able to write the above code with c:ForEach tags. 
So far, I have only been able to show the dropdown menu. But it doesn't save the value selected in its appropriate bean. This is the code I got:

```
<select>
    <c:forEach var="line" items="${availableLines}">
        <option><c:out value="${line}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Solution! Found it. Here is the code:

```
<form:select path="state" id="state"> 
<form:option value="NONE">Select   State: </form:option> 
<c:forEach items="${estateList}" var="stateslist"> 
<form:option value="${stateslist}">${stateslist}</form:option> 
</c:forEach> </form:select>
```

Comment: @BalusC  Hello, thanks for the link but my problem is not exactly the same. I have an ArrayList, not Maps. What is the equivalent of "${item.key}" when I am accessing ArrayList? Please help!

Comment: It doesn't matter. Point is just to let JSP print the `selected` attribute on the `<option>` element. The equivalent is just `${item}`.

Comment: @BalusC . After posting my last comments, I changed my list to a Map so that my code is similar. But then I noticed the link you provided, it has a selectedDept. But I am not sending two collections or values to Jsp. Just one. Now my code looks like this:  <select name="N/A"> <c:forEach var="item" items="${estateMap}"> <option value="${item.key}">${item.value}</option> </c:forEach> </select>. It still won't print the value selected in drop down menu.

Comment: @BalusC To be clear, I just want the value selected from the drop down menu to properly bind with an appropriate field in my bean. I can do it HTML way. There is a path attribute that I used to bind. Is there anything similar when I use JSTL? That was my original question and still is. Please Help!

Comment: Just compare it to `${student.ec[0].estate}`? After all, it look much like you'd better take a step back and practice a bit more with JSP based on a decent book.

Comment: @BalusC Hi. Your suggestion helped me. I read up on it and I successfully found a way to convert/include <c:/foreach> with <form:select>. It was easy. I used path attribute as well. Here is the code: <form:select path="state" id="state">
    <form:option value="NONE">Select State: </form:option>
    <c:forEach items="${estateList}" var="stateslist">
     <form:option value="${stateslist}">${stateslist}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
   </form:select>
I thought I would share what I found.